# C# Windows Service keep creating logs

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a problem on my windows service that keeps writing the same logs, anyone knows the solution for the service to not keep creating same logs like this? All that aside, my service is still running smoothly but it just keeps on creating logs files. If I open the log files, the timestamp for each log is for example 8:34:42 AM

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share what your logging framework of choice is and its configuration.

Comment: Maybe there are a lot of logging enabled in the Windows service configuration and you need to check the configuration.